# "Hello World" SOAP Web Service using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, soap

I want to write a hello world Spring MVC web service in Java. I'm really struggling to find a tutorial that goes to the basics to allow me to do this - ie. step by step for hello world.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'm struggling to find a step-by-step hello world tutorial..

Answer (score 7):

Spring Web Services (`Spring-WS`) is a product of the Spring community focused on creating `document-driven` Web services. It aims to facilitate contract-first SOAP service development. Some of its key features are:

- **Powerful mappings** The incoming XML requests can be distributed to any `object`, depending on `message payload`, SOAP Action header, or an XPath expression.
- **XML API support** Incoming XML messages can be handled not only with standard `JAXP` APIs such as `DOM`, `SAX`, and StAX, but also JDOM, dom4j, XOM, or even `marshalling` technologies.
- **Flexible XML Marshalling**  Spring Web Services builds on the
  Object/XML Mapping module in the Spring Framework, which supports
  `JAXB 1`, `JAXB 2`, `Castor`, `XMLBeans`, `JiBX`, and `XStream`.
- **Reuses your Spring expertise**  Spring-WS uses `Spring application contexts` for all configuration, which should help Spring developers get up-to-speed nice and quickly. Also, the architecture of `Spring-WS` resembles that of `Spring-MVC`.
- **Supports WS-Security**  WS-Security allows you to `sign` SOAP messages,
  encrypt and decrypt them, or `authenticate` against them.
- **Integrates with Spring Security**  The WS-Security implementation of Spring Web Services provides integration with `Spring Security`.

> Here are the List of tutorials and documentations to help to get
>   started with `Spring-ws`:

- [Youtube - Spring-WS Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfTmt_pUazU)
- [Spring Web Services Tutorial](http://briansjavablog.blogspot.in/2013/01/spring-web-services-tutorial.html)
- [Building a SOAP Webservices Proxy Module](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/building-a-soap-webservices-proxy-module-using-spring-webservices.html)
- [Official - Spring Web Services Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#what-is-spring-ws)
- [Spring 4 + SOAP Web Service Producer and Consumer Example](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-soap-web-service-producer-consumer-example-with-tomcat)

> SOAP is broad and complex topic, unlike REST API. You might want to get the concepts clear before starting with the implementation.

Comment: `Spring-ws` is a contract first web services framework, you will need to define the `wsdl` file first.