# Spring MVC soap webservice is not returning data from after ws call

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wcf, soap

i have created two spring projects in which one of them is soap service and from another i am calling the service that is the soap client. **i am able to call the soap service and send a string as parameter to the soap service**. But after call has done and after doing some operation on the soap service **it is not returning the data to the soap client**.

***controller class - client***

```
 controller.web_Service service = new controller.web_Service();
 controller.web_service.MutationEntry port = service.getWeb_ServicePort();
        String name = "ABC";    
        return  port.hello(name);
```

***webservice***

```
@WebService(serviceName = "soap_webservice")
public class soap_webservice {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String data) {
        return data + " DEF ";
    }
}
```

the client string value "ABC" is going nicely going to the service part. And it should return ABC + DEF that is ABCDEF as result. But i am getting null in the String name after webservice call.

> I have done same thing in simple java project without Spring MVC. It
>   works like charm.

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide your 'applicationContext.xml' file where you bind url and bean for implemented method 'hello'?

Comment: applicationcontext.xml is a spring config file. i have not done anything to that.

Comment: go ahead then :) it's a necessary part here

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/). I think it's exactly what you need :)
Or [this one](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-soap-web-service-producer-consumer-example-with-tomcat) if you are working in annotation based style.

Also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762027/hello-world-soap-web-service-using-spring-mvc). Here are a lot of usefull information about WS implementations.

Comment: but .. this is in eclipse. i am using netbeans.

Comment: it's no matter what IDE you use.. the source code will be the same :)

Comment: ok.. thanks.. i am going through what u have given.. hope it will solve.

Comment: one more thing ,, i spring in netbeans,, there are two files.. applicationContext.xml and dispatcherservlet.xml.. about which one of you are saying ?

Comment: You don't need dispatcher servlet at all because for WS you are using 'jaxws-servlet' instead. You should provide servlet mapping in web.xml file like in tutorial